# Echo simple string in Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am getting started with plugin development. I wrote the following program to display text on screen but nothing happened. Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Fahad
Plugin URI:
Description: Declares a plugin that will be visible in the
WordPress admin interface
Version: 1.0
Author: Yannick Lefebvre
Author URI: http://ylefebvre.ca
License: GPLv2
*/
?>


function fahad(){
    echo "I am alive";
}
add_filter('wp-footer', fahad);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subtle difference between your syntax `wp-footer`should be `wp_footer`, underscore `_` and not hypthen `-`

```
add_filter('wp-footer', fahad);   // wrong...

add_filter('wp_footer', 'fahad'); // right..
```

Follow the naming convention of functions:

- [(Codex) Plugin_API: Action_Reference » the `wp_footer` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)
- [(Codex) Plugin_API: Action_Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/)
- [(Codex) Function_Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)